# How to remove a letter with a space in Perl

Tags: perl

I am not that familiar with Perl, but I am processing some logs which have the date in the format of 2021-06-18T11:00:00. What I need to do is remove the letter T and replace it with a space. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl is absolutely in its element with text substitution. Specifically, we can use a simple [regular expression](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre). Assuming your line is in a variable called `$line`,

```
$line =~ s/T/ /;
```

Alternatively, if your variable is in the [implied variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$_) `$_` (such as if you're running in a `while (<>) {...}` loop, then you can omit the variable name

```
s/T/ /;
```